# Prove or disprove inequality: $2a^2 + 2b^2 + 3c^2 \ge 16P$

Tags: geometry, inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be the lengths of the sides of a triangle with area $P$ 
prove or disprove inequality:  $2a^2 + 2b^2 + 3c^2 \ge 16P$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz and the isoperimetric inequality don't suffice, in case someone else was about to try.

Comment: Note that we have equality when $a=b=\sqrt{5}$, $c=2$.

Comment: Is this true: $5c^4 - 4a^2b^2 \ge 0$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> $$2a^2 + 2b^2 + 3c^2 \overset{?}{\ge} 16P\tag{1}$$

**Hint:** It will be helpful to know [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) that provides a formula for the area of a triangle with sides length $a, b, c$:
$$P = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

where $ s=\dfrac{a+b+c}{2}$. This gives us

$$\text{Area}\;=\;\;P = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 2(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)}$$

where $a, b, c$ are the side lengths of a triangle

Substituting $P$ into your original inequality, you can work with proving/disproving the following inequality:

$$2a^2 + 2b^2 + 3c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 2(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)}\tag{2}$$

- **Start** with squaring each side of the inequality $(2)$. 
  (This is fine to do, without needing to consider a change in the direction of the inequality, because both sides are non negative.)
  $$(2a^2 + 2c^2 + 3c^2)^2 \geq 16(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 32(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)\tag{3}$$
- If you need it, you also have the *triangle inequality* to work with to put additional restrictions on the inequality: $a + b\geq c,; b + c\geq a,\; a + c\geq b$.

Comment: I knew Heron's_formula but I still can prove the inequality, please make more detail
--------------
I am stuck at $2a^2 + b^2 + 3c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 2(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)}$ already

Comment: Those are helpful details to have included in your original post. Have your tried squaring **each side** of the equation, cancelling/simplifying where possible, gathering like terms?

Comment: $2a^2 + b^2 + 3c^2 \geq 4\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)^2 - 2(a^4 + b^4 + c^4)} \\ \iff 20\,{a}^{4}-24\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-20\,{a}^{2}{c}^{2}+20\,{b}^{4}-20\,{b}^{2}{c}^{2}+25\,{c}^{4}
$
But still stuck

Comment: @D3r0X4 That is relatively easy to prove, and you do not even need triangle inequality.

Comment: @D3r0X4 **Hint:** Write as sum of squares.

Comment: Wonderful, D3r0X4! You're welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Let two of the sides be $a$ and $b$, and let the angle between them be $\theta$.

Then the area is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$, so $16$ times that is $8ab\sin\theta$.

By the Cosine Law, the square $c^2$ of the third side is $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta$. It follows that 
$$2a^2+2b^2+3c^2=5a^2+5b^2-6ab\cos\theta.$$
We are interested in proving the inequality 
$$5a^2+5b^2-6ab\cos\theta\overset{?}{\ge} 8ab\sin\theta,$$
or equivalently 
$$5a^2-2ab(3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta)+5b^2 \overset{?}{\ge} 0.$$
We would like to show that the discriminant is non-positive. So we would like to show that
$$(3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta)^2 \overset{?}{\le} 25.$$
This comes down to computing the maximum of $|3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta|$. But that maximum is $5$. There are many ways to show this. For example, let $\phi$ be the angle whose sine is $\frac{3}{5}$ and whose cosine is $\frac{4}{5}$. Then
$3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta=5\sin(\theta+\phi)$.

**Remark:** We have equality when $a=b=\sqrt{5}$ and $c=2$.

Comment: $(3\cos\theta+4\sin\theta)^2 \le 25$ is just Cauchy -Schwartz ;)

Comment: Sure, but I wanted a fully school-level proof.

Comment: There is an extremal problem whose answer leads to the 3-4-5 triangle?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short algebraic proof.  Since both sides are homogeneous of degree $2$, we can rescale to the case where $c=1$.  Then  by translating $A$ to the origin and by rotating so that $B$ lies at $(1,0))$ , we can reduce to the case where $A=(0,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C$ is $(p,q)$ for some $p$ and $q$.  The inequality then becomes
$$2(p^2+q^2) + 2((p-1))^2 + q^2) + 3 \geq 16 q.$$
This is,  by simple algebra, equivalent to the valid inequality 
$ (p-\frac 12 )^2+(q-1)^2 \geq 0$.